# Wcf transactions and SQL stored procedures

Tags: c#, wcf, transactions

I have a wcf service which has methods which perform insert/update operations in an SQL db via stored procedures. If I enable transactions for the wcf service and call 2 methods from my client using transaction scope will the individual SQL operations also get rolled back in case of a failure.

Comment: If you're using Oracle it it will rollback as long as you don't call the commit method; however, you should explicitly catch exceptions and rollback so you don't lock your database up.

Comment: No. I am not using oracle. I use mssql and I do have commit called within my stored procedure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Enabling transactions in WCF is not enough. According to [Transactions in WCF Services](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff384250.aspx) example you need to do the following:

- Add transaction support to the service contract. This is required.
- Add transaction support to the code that implements the service contract. This is required.
- Configure transactions in the implementation code. This is optional.
- Enable transactions on the binding. This is required.